# Is it possible to set a custom resolution (window size) in Dark Souls?

Tags: dark-souls

I'm playing Dark Souls: Prepare to Die Edition and I'm having a bit of an annoyance. I always play my games, if possible, in a custom resolution (in my case 1900 x 1000), so that the game's window almost takes my whole screen, but there is room for its title bar and Windows' taskbar.

I tried to do that in Dark Souls (both in the configuration file in my Documents folder and in DSFix's options), but it had no effect. The window always took my full screen, 1920 x 1080.

Then I tried the option for a borderless full screen window, and that worked rather well (minus the frustration from not seeing my taskbar) until I found that at some point, after a few alt-tabs, the window will soon become unusable, because it'll set itself to be behind everything else, and as a result all you can see of the game is a very small strip through the transparent taskbar.

Now I'm playing in proper full screen, which is free of the borderless window's bug, but then there's the annoyance of having an annoying delay on each alt-tab, not to mention the game's sound is cut when I'm on another window, so if I'm attacked while I was busy elsewhere, I'll never know and will find myself by a bonfire when I come back. Although this last point, I'm not sure it's exclusive to full screen.

So uhm, how can I set my custom resolution and play comfortably, the way I'm used to?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set your custom windowed resolution using [DSFix](http://darksouls.nexusmods.com/mods/19/) by setting the resolution using

```
renderWidth 1900
renderHeight 1000
```

and using `forceWindowed 1`. Without force windowed, the game will use one of the preset resolutions.

That being said, I also found out that the intro scene was a bunch of white vertical lines and I could not enter the main menu or even start playing. I hope this won't be the case for everyone, but I fear it might.

Comment: Same effect for me, sadly. After all, it does say the options are not ready to be used. Is there no other way? ._.

Comment: @Ariane I couldn't find another way and I doubt there is one.

Comment: Sigh. Annoying. In Dark Souls' configuration file in the Documents folder, if I change the resolution by hand and then launch the game, the file gets overwritten again and my custom values gets replaced by 1920 and 1080. Say, I'd like to try something. How, in Windows' security options, would I forbid Dark Souls from modifying its configuration file? If I'm lucky it just won't overwrite it instead of giving me the expected error message.

Comment: @Ariane you can flag the file read-only after editing, before launching the game. That might help. I cannot find any configuration in my Documents to test it out.

Comment: That's odd. I was sure there was such a file and I was sure I had modified it and seen it be overwritten by Dark Souls, but now I can't find it at all either. I guess I confused it with something else.

Comment: I found it. `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\NBGI\DarkSouls\DarkSouls.ini`. But I didn't manage to force the game to take the custom settings. It did re-edit the file itself if not on read only (once at startup with no noticeable changes, and once when quitting the game with the resolution back to 1920x1080), but once I locked the file, even though it didn't edit it, it kept its settings. Feels like it saves its settings elsewhere, too.